# using wildcards in java method overrides

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, wildcard, overriding

Most of the examples of generics and wildcards involve collections but I am trying to learn how to use them just with classes.  I want to learn this more modern approach of generics so that I can avoid the awkward casting that comes about when the subclass overrides a method from the superclass.

I have an abstract class for a guessing game that could potentially be used for a number guessing game, a word guessing game, or even Mastermind.  Included in the games package are abstract classes for Level and Score.  I would then like to subclass the guessing game and subclass the level and the score in order to make a specific game.

Here is the abstract class for Score:

```
// a score is a measure of how close a guess is to being correct
public abstract class Score{

    public abstract boolean equals(Class<? extends Score> otherScore);

    public abstract boolean isWin(Class<? extends Level> level);

}
```

In writing the parameter for isWin, I was trying to say: expect to get an argument of something that is either a Level or a subclass of Level.

I then made my subclass of Score for Mastermind:

```
public class MastermindScore extends games.Score{
    int numRightPlace;
    int numWrongPlace;


    public MastermindScore(int numRightPlace, int numWrongPlace){
            this.numRightPlace = numRightPlace;
            this.numWrongPlace = numWrongPlace;
    }

    public boolean equals(MastermindScore otherScore){
            if (this.numRightPlace==otherScore.numRightPlace){
                    if (this.numWrongPlace == otherScore.numWrongPlace){
                            return true;
                    }
            }
            return false;
    }

    public boolean isWin(MastermindLevel level){
            return this.numRightPlace == level.numSlots;
    }
```

This does not compile because it believes that I have not correctly overridden the methods required by the abstract superclass.  So, even though the subclass' isWin method has a parameter that is a subclass of Level, it doesn't recognize that as the expected type.

I then changed the class declaration line for the subclass of Level to look like this:

```
public class MastermindLevel<T extends games.Level>{

    public final int numColors;
    public final int numSlots;


    public MastermindLevel(int numColors, int numSlots, int maxGuesses){
            super(maxGuesses);
            this.numColors = numColors;
            this.numSlots = numSlots;
    }
}
```

However, when I do this, the call to the superclass constructor does not work because it believes my class to be a subclass of Object, not a subclass of Level.

I know I can get the code to work by writing the overridden methods with parameters of the superclass and then casting Level and Score to MastermindLevel and MastermindScore, but I was hoping to learn how/if this can be done with generics.  I really would like to understand generics more thoroughly.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You're doing it wrong. You most likely want something like `<T extends Level> boolean isWin(T level)`.

Answer (score 3):

Note that in your abstract class `Score`, your methods are accepting a `java.lang.Class` object.

In your class `MastermindScore` however, you're using the types `MastermindScore` and `MastermindLevel` for the method parameters. That's not going to work, because the types are not the same as in the superclass, and `MastermindScore` is not a subclass of `Class<? extends Score>`, etc.

Do something like this instead:

```
public abstract class Score<S extends Score, L extends Level> {

    public abstract boolean equals(S otherScore);

    public abstract boolean isWin(L level);
}

public class MastermindScore extends Score<MastermindScore, MastermindLevel> {

    public boolean equals(MastermindScore otherScore) {
        // ...
    }

    // etc.
}
```

Comment: thanks, Jesper.  It now compiles, although I get a warning:

`games.Score is a raw type. References to generic type games.Score<S,L> should be parameterized`

Can you help me understand the concept here?  I appreciate it.

Comment: This is because `Score` is a generic type in `S, L` and the method `equals` takes a `Score` without a generic type - a rawtype. This approach is a little flawed for that reason. In any case, `equals` should take an `Object` if you want to override the `equals` method.

Comment: actually, the warning is coming up on the class declaration line for the superclass `public abstract class Score<S extends Score, L extends Level>{`   
I do understand that overriding the equals method from class Object would require a parameter of an Object, but I am not trying to override that method.  I am just using the name equals because it is a good description of what I want, to see if one score is the same as another.

Comment: @NinaKoch The reason is the same - `Score` is parametrised and the declaration is not. Specifically the use of `Score` in `S extends Score`.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do this, your method declaration:

```
public abstract boolean isWin(Class<? extends Level> level);
```

says that your method takes a `Class` that has a `Type` of `Score` or some subclass. So `Score.class` would work as a parameter. i.e. you are asking for the `Class` not an instance of it.

So what you really want is:

```
public abstract<L extends Level> boolean isWin(L level);
```

this is a generic method. But this doesn't really add much to your code as when you use `L` all the compiler can say is that `L` is a `Level` - you would still need to cast.

So what you really need is a generic `interface`:

```
public interface Score<L> {

    boolean isWin(L level);    
}
```

When you the create your other implementation you would do:

```
public class MastermindScore implements Score<MastermindLevel> {
```

And you would need a method:

```
boolean isWin(MastermindLevel level);
```

And obviously `MastermindLevel` would need to `extends Level`.

Also note that `equals` is implemented as `equals(Object other)` and so you **must** cast. You should not have an `equals(MyType other)` method.